# How to fully stop UAC Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, uac, privileges

I have a problem, i have a Windows 8 realease Preview. I have UAC turned off always, but for test i switched UAC on (slider up) and restarted my pc, then, i turned it off (slider down) and restarted my pc. And now have a problem, all .exe files starts without admin privileges (my pc user is administrator). How can i fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested with the release version the release preview version is a beta product.

Answer (score 4):

You can fully disable UAC through the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, set EnableLUA to 0).

However, on Windows 8, this will stop Metro apps from working until you turn it back on, and is therefore not recommended.